# endpointscfg.py does not work when ResourceContainer is defined two or more

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I defined two ResourceContainer.

But echov1openapi.json is generated by endpointscfg.py has only one Container.

such as:

```
class TestRequest(messages.Message):
    foo = messages.StringField(1)
    bar = messages.StringField(2)

class EchoRequest(messages.Message):
    aaa = messages.StringField(1)
    bbb = messages.StringField(2)

ECHO_RESOURCE = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
    EchoRequest,
    n=messages.IntegerField(3))

TEST_RESOURCE   = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
    TestRequest,
    test=messages.IntegerField(3))
...
    @endpoints.method(
        ECHO_RESOURCE,
        EchoResponse,
        path='echo',
        http_method='POST',
        name='echoTest')
    def echo(self, request):
        ...    
    @endpoints.method(
        TEST_RESOURCE,
        EchoResponse,
        path='echo2',
        http_method='POST',
        name='echo2')
    def echo2(self, request):
        ....
```

then, I execute endpointscfg.py. But TEST_RESOURCE is not appears.

```
  "definitions": {
...
    "ProtorpcMessagesCombinedContainer": { ★ECHO_RESOURCE
      "properties": {
        "aaa": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "bbb": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "n": {
          "format": "int64",
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
...
  "paths": {
    "/echo/v1/echo": {
      "post": {
        "operationId": "EchoApi_echo",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/ProtorpcMessagesCombinedContainer"★refer ECHO_RESOURCE
            }
          }
        ],
...
    "/echo/v1/echo2": {
      "post": {
        "operationId": "EchoApi_echo2",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/ProtorpcMessagesCombinedContainer"★not TEST_RESOURCE but ECHO_RESOURCE! 
            }
          }
        ],
```

Is it specification or BUG?
ResourceContainer can be defined once each API?

and I could not found API reference about ResourceContainer.
Where is the reference page?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without seeing your full example, but I suspect the cause is that you never *use* the 'test' attribute in any of the requests; you don't accept a 'test' url parameter.